# See which ID is connected to which table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am playing around in a SQL database and I'm trying to figure out how all these tables are connected to each other, which is quite complicated in my head. Is there an easy way to see, if I click on an ID/Primarykey/Foreignkey which other tables they are connected to?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15#create-a-foreign-key-relationship-in-table-designer

Comment: https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2016/tutorial/create_a_relationship_in_sql_server_2016.cfm

Comment: They show you how to create a relationship. You can use the same screen in SSMS to view existing ones, too.

Comment: Another thing you can consider is using a tool to generate a diagram of all (or part) of the database, e.g. https://dataedo.com/tutorials/create-database-diagram

Comment: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html

Comment: This was brilliant. Thank you for your answers, problem is solved!